# iOS Converting milliseconds to date returns wrong time

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to convert milliseconds into date. Below shown is the code i am using.

```
 double startDateDb=1380275880000;
 NSDate *date=[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(startDateDb/1000.0)];
 NSLog(@"date---%@",date);
```

My log gives date as 2013-09-27 09:58:00 +0000

When i use online tool to convert i am getting "9/27/13 5:58 AM" which is correct.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: Your time zone is UTC -4, your date is logged UTC-0, and 4 hours ahead, so it *is* correct.

Comment: Time zone, time zone, time zone, time zone!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog used your timezone when displaying dates. TO get the date in UTC use the NSDate methods and specify the tie zone. All NSDates are UTC timezone based.

Use `NSDateFormatter` to display the date/time in another timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Your NSLog put the timezone in GMT, the timezone you're looking for is GMT-4.